# Does the initialization of a thread object lead to background thread (Android)?

Tags: java, android, multithreading, background

I was searching for days for some information that helps me with **Threads**. my question is does this statement
`Thread th = new Thread()`
 leads to having a background  Thread?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: no, did you check the doc?, there is a ***start*** method...

Comment: @ΦXocę웃Пepeúpaツ thanks for the reply, I know that the thread won't do anything unless I call the **start()** method on the thread, however, does the invocation of the **start()** method leads to background thread ???

Comment: then yes... as soon as you call start your thread will be executed separately...(if that is what you mean with background....)

Comment: @ΦXocę 웃 Пepeúpa ツ yes that's what i mean thank you btw does the code that runs in separate thread than the ui thread work in background ?

Answer (score 0):

To manage background operations you need to use the AsyncTask class .

check this documentation : https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

Comment: thanks for the guides 
i went and read the 
[link](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/processes-and-threads.html) page and
[link](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) page  and get some information but my real goal  does this statement **Thread th = new Thread **
is the base of creating a background thread?